# How connect to proxy in electron webview?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, electron, atom-editor

as I can connect through a  to a free proxy server (or pay), currently in use as electron JS solution as desktop application

example proxy list servers

http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [.setProxy()](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/session/#sessetproxyconfig-callback) method of session object. You're able to specify proxy directly like in example below:

```
// in main.js
var electron      = require('electron');
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    "width": 970,
    "height": 500,
    "center": true,
    'title': 'Main window',
});
mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules:"socks5://114.215.193.156:1080"}, function () {
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://whatismyipaddress.com/');
});
```

Or you can use PACscript:

```
// in main.js
mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({pacScript:"file://"+root+"/js/pacfile.js"}, function () {
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://whatismyipaddress.com/');
});


// pacfile.js example
var blocked      = ["site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com"];
var proxyServer  = "SOCKS5 114.215.193.156:1080";
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var shost = host.split(".").reverse();
    shost = shost[1] + "." + shost[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < blocked.length; i++) {
        if( shost == blocked[i] ) return proxyServer;
    }
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I will be loading urls dynamically, can we set different proxy for different URL.

Comment: Watch out, in electron you are not allowed to use ```console.log```inside the FindProxyForURL function. You can test your script by using 
```mainWindow.webContents.session.resolveProxy(TEST_URL, function(x) {
      console.log(x)
    })```

Comment: Any ways to authentication?

Comment: this results in a blank page for me

Comment: this results in a blank page for me as well. Any solution. I tried `:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(997)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202`

Answer (score 3):

The chosen answer is somehow correct but the last changes on the library will make you to do this:

`setProxy` is now a Promise. So now you need to put the last function into the `.then()` function or use `await`. I hope this comment helps other people. I fixed mine like this:

```
mainWindow.webContents.session
.setProxy({proxyRules:"socks5://114.215.193.156:1080"})
.then(() => {
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://whatismyipaddress.com/');
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with suggested method in my context where I run separate browser views.

Instead of setting proxy on `BrowserWindow` I set proxy on the view:

```
view.webContents.session
      .setProxy({
        proxyRules: proxyString,
      })
```

then using `app.on('login')` handler to authorize proxy.

Comment: Does it work authorization by proxy server ?

Any example of it ?