# How connect to proxy in electron webview-dynamically

Tags: webview, electron

I am creating simple web browser using Electron. My use case is I need to route each URL via different/respective proxy-IPs. If the user type **google.com** it has to route via `123.123.122.1:8081` and if he type `gmail.com` it has to route via `111.111.111.123:8080` [Proxy/Port].I saw this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393248/how-connect-to-proxy-in-electron-webview?rq=1` but it will not change proxy dynamically. Is it possible to do it in electron.

Comment: Hi Jeya, did you finally solved this?

Comment: @ViceSallés : please check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem.
Either you can use proxy.pac method or session/proxy rules to change the proxy

persist session method :

```
var proxyIp ='12.12.133.12’
var port =‘8080’

<webview id="wv1" src="https://github.com" partition="persist:webviewsession"></webview>

if(proxyIp.trim() =='noproxy'){
    var my_proxy = 'direct://';
    session.fromPartition('persist:webviewsession').setProxy({proxyRules:my_proxy}, function (){
        console.log('using the proxy  '  + proxyIp);
    });

}else{
    var my_proxy = "http://"+proxyIp+":"+port;
    session.fromPartition('persist:webviewsession').setProxy({proxyRules:my_proxy}, function (){
        console.log('using the proxy  '  + proxyIp);
    });
}
```

proxy.pac method

proxy.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const {session} = require('electron')
let mainWindow;
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  app.quit();
});

  app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1024, height: 768 });
  session.defaultSession.allowNTLMCredentialsForDomains('*')//to access internal sites

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 3000);
function myTimer() {
   mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({pacScript:'file://' + __dirname + '/proxy.pac'}, function () {return true;});
}

mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({pacScript:'file://' + __dirname + '/proxy.pac'}, function () {mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/browser.html');});
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
});
```

proxy.pac

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

   if (shExpMatch(url, "*google*"))
         return "PROXY 164.83.99.74:80";

   if (shExpMatch(url, "*amazon*"))
         return "PROXY 194.73.29.74:8080";

   return "DIRECT";

}
```

Proxy.pac file can be in some S3 location or in some other remote server or local so even if you change remote proxy.pac file that will reflect in electron tool.Issue with proxy.pac method is when ever you are changing proxy IP in proxy.pac u need to reload proxy.pac file in electron that's why i am reloading every 3 sec in above code.

Both will work fine and I tested both myself.
You can use any based on your usecase.

Detailed discussion can be found here 
https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-set-proxy-for-each-webview-tag-in-electronjs/37307/2

Electron Document : [https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#sessetproxyconfig-callback](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8247#issuecomment-268435712)

Suggestion from electron maintainer : 
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8247#issuecomment-268435712

Comment: could you please put the full code, Its not working for me.